# How to navigate between screens of different StackNavigators under SwitchNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

The configuration is as follows:

```
SwitchNavigator
    LoadingScreen: Component
    App: StackNavigator
        ProfileScreen
        DashboardScreen
    SignInFlow: StackNavigator
        LoginScreen  // <= Initially we're here
        LikeScreen
    SignUpFlow: StackNavigator
        SignUpScreen // <= The goal is to navigate to here
        TCScreen
```

Then there is a very common pattern you see on Login screens:

> Don't have an account? [Sign Up]

So

1. we are in `LoginScreen` above.
2. We click a button '[Sign Up]'
3. We have to be navigated to `SignUpFlow`'s `SignUpScreen`.

We should keep in mind that we use `SwitchNavigator` as a parent for our StackNavigators.

So the state of the app/routes on navigation from StackNavigator to StackNavigator [must be reset to defaults](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html).

> The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away.

The goal is to navigate from `SignUpScreen` to `LoginScreen`.

How to implement this common pattern with React Navigator with configuration above?

Environment is React Native for IOS

Comment: I think you should combine `SignInFlow` and `SignUpFlow`. As a UX point of view, user might want to go back after he landed on `SignUp` after he remembered that he has an account already. Other than that as it shows in [example snack](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow) you can just do `this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpFlow')`.

Comment: @bennygenel, I think I'll be compelled to do what you say - to combine `SignInFlow` and `SignUpFlow`. Because I can't see ready solution in that library for my config. But I'm curious if it is possible though. Very common use case.

Comment: I don't think you have to do it. It should work with the current configuration. Mine was just a suggestion. Did you try to do an example project see if it is going to work or not?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to navigate from a stackNavigator to another one , you can use NavigationActions like this :

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
routeName: 'the name of the stack route',

params: {},

action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'route' , params : {"maybe you want to send the use name or email ... "} }),
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```